# how to print sum of squares of n numbers in clojure using loop/recur

Tags: loops, clojure, tail-recursion

I am trying the below code, but it gives an error:

```
(defn sum-square [n]
       (loop [i 0 result 0]
           (if (<= i n) 
               (do    
                   (recur (inc i) (conj result (+ result (* i i))))))))  
(def n (Integer/parseInt (clojure.string/trim (read-line))))
(sum-square n)
```

Comment: `(conj result (+ result (* i i)))` replace with `(+ result (* i i))`

Comment: Already tried that. Doesn't work

Comment: do is unneccessary, and missing else branch from if so `if (<= i n) (recur (inc i) (+ result (* i i))) result`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about the else part. It works now.

Comment: You are redefining a global `n` on each invocation.  Use `let` to create local bindings.

Comment: @cske Please consider posting this as an answer instead of a comment given that it solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
(defn sum-square [n]
  (->> (range n) 
       (map *) 
       (reduce +))
```

You could also write it like this.

Comment: Or like this:

    (defn sum-square [n] (transduce (map #(* % %)) + (range n)))